# Why does the $E$ vs $k$ curve disrupt at Bragg planes?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory, dispersion

Interaction between 'nearly free' or 'bound' electrons is what leads to bands. I understand this but why specifically at Brillouin zone boundaries?